# Jupyter-like docstring view in Atom.io

Tags: python, autocomplete, atom-editor, jupyter, docstring

This question has to do with getting Jupyter Notebook docstring functionality to work in Atom. I appreciate any and all advisement.

[image: Jupyter Notebook]

In the Jupyter Notebook you are able to access the docstring via shift-tab and expand and scroll through the docstring as well as select and copy-paste from it into the cells.

[image: Atom Editor running IPykernel]

In the Atom Editor running the IPykernel I can see part of the docstring via autocomplete-python package, but I am unable to scroll through the docstring's full length, nor am I able to select from it for copy-pasting.

I cannot find a hotkey to make Atom open a browsable and selectable docstring as in Jupyter Notebook. Anybody have any ideas?

My keycap.cson file contains the following:

```
 'atom-text-editor': 'enter':
         'editor:newline' 'shift-tab': 'language-python: toggle-all-docstrings'
```

But this does nothing....

Comment: My keycap.cson file contains the following:

'atom-text-editor':
  'enter': 'editor:newline'
  'shift-tab': 'language-python: toggle-all-docstrings'

But this does nothing....

Comment: That comment should be an edit to the question; as you can see, pasting CSON into a common makes it difficult to read.

Comment: Advise take and applied.

Comment: Well I suppose this is irrelevant now since I have been happily using VS Code for the last 3 months.

Comment: I would like to add that if you want to use shift+tab like in Jupyter Notebook, you need to add this line to keymap.cson 'atom-text-editor:not([mini])': 'shift-tab': 'hydrogen:toggle-inspector' (shift-tab is on new line)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I added the bounty but I actually managed to figure out the answer.

1) Download a package called `hydrogen` from the `packages` in atom. 

2) Go to your .py file in atom and hold `ctrl-shift-p`. A search bar will pop up

3) type `hydrogen: toggle inspector` and a window will pop at the bottom

4) go to the variable where you want to view the strings and simply press `alt-i`. That is the equivalent of `tab` in the Jupiter notebook

Comment: I would like to add that if you want to use shift+tab like in Jupyter Notebook, you need to add this line to keymap.cson `'atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'shift-tab': 'hydrogen:toggle-inspector'` (shift-tab is on new line)

Comment: @Biarys please included in the edit in the same answer above so other users can see it

Comment: you mean create a separate answer or add comment on the op?

Comment: `toggle inspector` doesn't show up in my hydrogen drop down...